# How can I turn On and Off Accessibility Service programmably?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Manually it can be done by going through settings menu ,but is there an API android exposes to change this setting through some function call?

What I want to achieve is to disable TalkBack when my app runs. More precise I just want to disable Explore By Touch  feature of TalkBack.

So any of these will do

a)Disable Accessiblity Service OR
b)Disable TalkBack             OR
c)Disable TalkBack feature Explore By Touch

Comment: I feel like this question has been asked before, but I cannot locate it. Why do you want to disable the service, are you making your own implementation?>

Comment: @RyanB My app make use of gestures , but when "Explore By Touch" is enabled it steals all the gestures away from my app .

Comment: Are you doing something to compensate?

Comment: compensate when you disable explore by touch

Answer (score 0):

A little late on this one, but perhaps it will help someone.

In my main class I used an intent for my accessibility service class. I had an on off switch with which I would pass a boolean over whether or not I wanted the access

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch onOffSwitch;
Intent serviceIntent;

public void onOff(View view){
    if(onOffSwitch.isChecked()){
        Log.i("Main Switch", "Turn on please");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("onOffService", true);
    }
    else{
        Log.i("Main Switch", "Turn off please");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("onOffService", false);
    }

    this.startService(serviceIntent);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    onOffSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.onOffSwitch);
    serviceIntent= new Intent(this, myService.class);

}
}
```

Then in myService class I would receive the intent with an onStartCommand. This seemed to work fine for me.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    onOffService = intent.getBooleanExtra("onOffService", true);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I would then use the boolean inside functions to determine whether or not I wanted the Service to be active.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Accessibility service by simply calling
 
`disableSelf();`

Note: This will turn off Service from Settings also. You need to Re-take again from the user. 
If you want to turn off temporarily use Blazej Gawlik approach instead.